# "node is not recognized as an internal or external command" and "[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1)."while running"ionic serve"

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I am running v12.3.1 version of nodejs and 6.9.0 of npm.
while running 
"ionic serve" command from visual code terminal, gives me above error.

I checked environment variables and PATH in the system, nodejs, npm both are there with correct folder path.

$ ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
>   [ng] 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [ng] operable program or batch file.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```